# Do the brcm80211 drivers need patching to work correctly in airmon etc?

Tags: 11.04, wireless, networking, broadcom

I am trying to use the broadcom brcm80211 drivers along with a BCM4313 chip and aircrack-ng suite of programs but airodump only ever lists clients for WEP protected access points. I have setup a WPA2 router and connected another device to it so I know there is definately a client but I never pick it up. Can anyone offer any advice?

sadly there is alot of junk relating to getting this chipset functioning even in a basic way with linux so if you google it you will get hits relating to propietary drivers, b43 legacy and also kernel source which is what currently is in use. The drivers function fantastic in normal operation. Monitor mode obviously works, I'm not certain about the injection, some things hint at it working and others point to it failing.

```
Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01)
```

Update: The kernel driver still needs more development to work for penetration testing purposes but the responsiveness for regular wifi use is far superior to the wl or sta drivers.

Comment: Have you asked the people over at air-crack?

Answer (score 1):

it is my experience that most Wireless card can not do some of the basic Air-Crack options without been altered in some way with an injection (Take mental note that I do not know what aircrack is or have I ever used it in anyway). if you read the changelog you will see that some drivers for wireless cards receive a "patch" which is the injected code that lets them do.. what they do in air-crack: http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=changelog

Afterwards if you read the compatibility list you will see which ones Air-Crack supports without a patch, which ones need a patch and which ones work mostly: http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=compatibility_drivers

For example, for the Broadcom you can find if it is supported here: http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=b43 and do the injection test in that same page to see if it qualifies.

Also in the air crack forum you can find guides to "patch" the Wireless card. There are other testing softwares like Backtrack which include a lot of patches already or Metasploit. Anyway with this is enough to determine if you need to patch or not. Good luck friend.